# Display WordPress CPT items on one page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Okey, this is probably a very noob question, but I was wondering how I can display all the Custom Post Type items on one page in my WordPress child theme?

My child theme has the files:
**functions.php** and **style.css**

Let's say my CPT is named **songs** and I would like to display all the songs on a page called **example.com/music**

Anyone have any idea how to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a CPT with the name *songs*, your post has the `post_type` *songs* and you can query it like any other `post_type` and print it in a loop:

```
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'songs', 'posts_per_page' => '5', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'offset' => 0));
if(have_posts()) {
    while(have_posts()) : the_post();
        get_template_part('content', 'songs');
    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();
```

In the above example I use an optional content template for the html rendering of the `post_type` to structure my code more.

So there will be a file in my template folder with the name `content-songs.php` where I can define the output of the CPT:

```
<article class="songs">
    <header>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header>

    <div>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
</article>
```

To output your CPT in a page you can use *page templates* which are something like "custom page types". An simple example for a page template is the following snippet. To use a page template you need to create a file in your template folder which is called `page-songs.php` for example.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Songs
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage YOUR THEME NAME
 * @since MyTheme 2.0
 */
get_header();

?>
    <div class="song-list">
        <?php
        query_posts(array('post_type' => 'songs', 'posts_per_page' => '5', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'offset' => 0));
        if(have_posts()) {
            while(have_posts()) : the_post();
                get_template_part('content', 'songs');
            endwhile;
        }
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>
    </div>
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Now the CPT output code is included in a page template. You just need to create a new page in Wordpress and choose (in a newly appeared dialog) which template the page should use. Here will now also be the Template *Songs* available. After creating your page you should see the songs of your CPT.

Comment: I see. Where would I put the query? I'm still learning WordPress so I thought there would be a file like music.php?

Comment: Okey, so I've created the file `content-songs.php` and pasted in the article. I've tried adding the query both to my `functions.php` file and the `content-songs.php` file, but still nothing.

Comment: The first query code block is just an example of how you can output your CPT.
It highly depends on where you want to output your CPT and if you want to mix up these with other post types. One easy example is, to put the first code snippet into your `sidebar.php` for example. But in general it have to be put into a place in the template which gets rendered by wordpress (eg. `index.php`, `page-XYZ.php`, `sidebar.php`...)

Comment: I edited my answer to give you an example of the above written.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help!